# error while replacing text using re module

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace some text in a string. I have "Microsoft Inc." and I want to replace it as "Microsoft Incorporation". For this I have tried like

```
company = 'Microsoft Inc.'
key = 'Inc.'
pattern = r'\b' + key + r'\b'
# pattern = r'\b' + re.escape(key) + r'\b'
_change = 'Incorporation'
y = re.sub(pattern, _change, company)
print(y)
```

I dont see any replacements. but when I remove "." from company and key then it is working fine, but when there is "." in string it doesnt change any thing.

Comment: First of all, escape variables, `re.escape(key)`. Second, do not use `\b` if you have special chars at the start/end of words, use `(?<!\w)` / `(?!\w)` or `(?<!\S)` / `(?!\S)` custom boundaries.

Comment: thank you @Wiktor Stribizew: it worked !